How to send cookies from the local host to a back-end
My Auth API issues this cookie like this and sends it to the client (client is localhost)
res.cookie("token", accessToken, {
    httpOnly: true,
    maxAge: 3456000000,
})

My client runs locally on the computer during development, whereas the API runs on a server with a domain. This runs with HTTPS
Now I want to send the cookie to my RESTful API, with axios
export const RequestRESTfulAPIv1 = axios.create({
    baseURL: "https://dev-kjpsqalo.example.net/",
    withCredentials: true,
})

However, the token cookie is not sent to the RESTful API.
I have tried to use SameSite=None, without success, I have also tried Secure but this only works if my client is also HTTPS. I have tried this with mkcert but it still does not send the cookie to the RESTful API
If the API and the client are running locally, the transfer of cookies works, why not if the API is linked to a domain on a server?
